# iptables recent inverse matching IP

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to write iptables rules with an explicit whitelist, that any new unseen traffic should bypass the iptables rules for 60 seconds, in order to give time for further processing of the traffic by an application.  If the packet cannot authenticate with the application within 60 seconds, then rules should be processed further.  (Fail2Ban is NOT an option here, reason is beyond the scope of this post).

My idea here was to use 2 RECENT lists, and tag packets that have not yet been seen with WHITELIST, and allow them for 60 seconds with rcheck, and afterward add those packets to another list called WLFAIL for further processing.  If the packet is not in WLFAIL, then add them to WHITELIST, like this:

```
//#1 - First allow packets in the whitelist for 60 seconds
-A RULELIST -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 1 --name WHITELIST --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j ACCEPT
//#2 - You're not in the WHITELIST, if you're not in the WLFAIL list we'll add you to WHITELIST
-A RULELIST -m recent ! --rcheck --name WLFAIL --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j addtowhitelist
//#3 - Since you're in WLFAIL, you don't belong in WHITELIST anymore
-A RULELIST -m recent --remove --name WHITELIST --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource
...
//#4 - This should add to WHITELIST
-A addtowhitelist -m recent --set --name WHITELIST --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j ACCEPT
```

Line #2 never seems to match, and I can't seem to find the correct syntax for inverse matching "not in the list".  Am I misunderstanding what the Bang does, and what would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake in my own code - I had a typo in the -j.

So, for anyone else with this question - the syntax in line #2 is correct - you can match inversely against a list.